# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in EventsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

After adding new column events_count to table `users`, I get this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: events_count: UPDATE "users" SET "events_count" = COALESCE("events_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "users"."id" = 2
```

This is extracted source with a line with bug:

```
@event.user_id = current_user.id
respond_to do |format|
  **if @event.save**
    format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
  else
```

This is my users table:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  .
  .
  .
  .
  t.integer  "events_count",           default: 0
end
```

This is html with ranking from users_path:

```
<tr>
  <% User.all.each  do |user| %> 
    <td> <%= user.name %></td>
    <td> <%= user.events_count %></br></td> 
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

This is Event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_commontable
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy,counter_cache: true
end
```

Anyone know what may be wrong?

EDIT:

This is migration file:

```
class AddEventsCountToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :events_count, :integer, :default => 0
  end
end
```

This is Event controller:

```
# POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user_id = current_user.id 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :picture, :start_date, :start_time, :end_time, :location, :user_id, :city)
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you done `rake db:migrate` after that?

Comment: have you run a migration for adding this **events_count** column or added it yourself in that migration ?

Comment: I done rake db:migrate after that and i run a migration for adding events_count.

Comment: rake db:migrate VERSION='XXXXXX'  (include version of migration file which u changed ex: 54321_create_users.rb  ... rake db:migrate VERSION='54321' )

Comment: I tried but it's not help

Comment: try this rake db:migrate:redo this should help you

Comment: Please could you update your question accurately with migration, model and error details.  If you have typos in field names it's important you correct these otherwise it's difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Did this query `AddEventsCountToUsers` createad a file with column_name `event_counts`?Or its another typo? It should create a column with the name `events_count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just added `event_counts` instead of `events_count` that to an already existing `create_users.rb` migration file.

you have to perform a query which generates a migration file for an extra column `events_count`

```
rails g migration AddEventsCountToUsers events_count:integer
```

Do rake db:migrate after that

**OR**

Do `rake db:rollback`,add that column in the `create_users.rb` migration file and do `rake db:migrate`

As mentioned in the comments,try running `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140511122817`

Comment: I made it exactly as you wrote.

Comment: @Koin Arab Do you created an extra migration file for events_count by running this query `rails g migration AddEventsCountToUsers events_count:integer` or you just added it in the `create_users.rb` migration file?

Comment: I running query:rails g migration AddEventsCountToUsers events_count:integer

Comment: @KoinArab Can you Post the file name of that?

Comment: @KoinArab No,I need the file name please.

Comment: 20140511122817_add_events_count_to_users.rb

Comment: @KoinArab Then try running `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140511122817`

Answer (score 0):

Edit user table as:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
.
.
.
.
 t.integer  :events_count, default: 0
end
```

And run these commands:-

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

**Note** :- It will delete all data from your datasase

Comment: This change only  event_counts to events_count. I know i made a typo but i made it when i running a migration so it should be ok.